# WSL2 cannot connect to remote SSH

Tags: openssh, wsl-2

I can't connect to remote SSH server from within WSL2. The cursor just blinks and nothing happens.

On the same machine, same Internet connection, I can connect to the same server from command prompt (Windows OpenSSH client).

I did reset WSL to no avail.

This is driving me crazy.